# Is name a special attribute when dealing with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function name(firstname)
    {
        alert("Your firstname: " + firstname);  
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input type="button" value="Do it" onclick="name('aaron')"/>
</form>
</body>
```

This will not work in Chrome/IE8. IE8 states Object doesn't support this action. It has to do with the name of the function being *name*. If I change the name of the function to *people* it works...what gives?

Comment: maybe you should name your function by what it does and not some general word.. like printName, print_name etc.

Comment: @ fazo Yes I should...however that does not in anyway address the cause of the issue...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a reserved word, and it's **not** a clash with `window.name`. There *are* problems with using a `window` property name as a global variable in IE, but it's OK as long as you have declared them globals using the `var` or `function` keywords as you have here.

What you have here is a strange—and, as far as I can see, undocumented—IE quirk (copied by WebKit) where, in event handlers declared via inline attribute, the properties of the target element are treated as local variables. This is presumably so you can write code like:

```
<input name="foo" value="bar" onclick="alert(name+': '+value)"/>  // foo: bar
```

'cos saying `this.name` is too hard, apparently. Once again IE trying to be “convenient” causes weird unpredictable bugs.

This is just another reason not to use inline event handler attributes. Without them:

```
<input id="doit" type="button" value="Do it"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('doit').onclick= function() {
        name('bob');
    };
</script>
```

works fine.

Comment: Anyway to verify this theory, it being handled as a local var? via output...etc...?

Comment: Well if you write to `name`, you'll find you're not making an accidental global or writing to `window.name`, as the `name` visible from a script outside the handler is unchanged, and instead the button's field name changes. If you say `onclick="value='hello'"` it makes it clearer what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the previous answers (sorry, I can't comment yet!), name is not exactly a reserved word.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Chrome misinterprets this line as trying to access the anonymous function (created by your inline event handler)

```
<input type="button" value="Do it" onclick="name('aaron');"/>
```

You can get the intended behavior by doing

```
<input type="button" value="Do it" onclick="window.name('aaron');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

"name" is an attribute of the window (global) object defined in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-name). It is NOT a reserved JavaScript word (you can find a list of reserved keywords [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)), but since it's defined in HTML5, using "name" as a function/variable name is not advisable for JavaScript code developed for use with HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `window` object (which is the global scope) already has a property named `name`.

The name `name` is not a reserved keyword, and works fine in other scopes (e.g. a local variable). You should avoid to use it though, as you might inadvertently use the property in the `window`object instead of the variable.

Comment: Why the downvote? It can't improve the answer if you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong.